# Principal variation in chess engine - How could I rewrite this C code into C#?

Tags: c#, c, struct, chess

I need help rewriting this code (the blue parts in the link) to C#. I have little experience with programming in C or C++, so I am not sure how exactly should I interpret the tagMove structure and -> operator in C#.

http://web.archive.org/web/20040427013839/brucemo.com/compchess/programming/pv.htm

---

If somebody doesn't want to click the link, I also posted the code here:

```
typedef struct LINE 
{
    int cmove;              // Number of moves in the line.
    MOVE argmove[moveMAX];  // The line.
}   
LINE;

int AlphaBeta(int depth, int alpha, int beta, LINE * pline) 
{

    LINE line;
    if (depth == 0) {
        pline->cmove = 0;
        return Evaluate();
    }
    GenerateLegalMoves();
    while (MovesLeft()) {

        MakeNextMove();
        val = -AlphaBeta(depth - 1, -beta, -alpha, &line);
        UnmakeMove();

        if (val >= beta) return beta;
        if (val > alpha) {
            alpha = val;
            pline->argmove[0] = ThisMove();
            memcpy(pline->argmove + 1, line.argmove, line.cmove * sizeof(MOVE));
            pline->cmove = line.cmove + 1;
        }
    }
    return alpha;
}
```

Comment: `pline->cmove` would become `pline.cmove`, where `pline` is an instance of the `LINE` object. As for `tagMove`, it's unclear what this is.

Answer (score 0):

You are mentioning that you don't know what the "->" operator does in C#, there it is just a "." if something contains a property you access it with a simple dot, lets say that we have an object country with some values, to access each one:

```
Country.Capital
Country.President
```

etc...

now, the problem with your question is that it is extremely basic, and there is nothing wrong with that, we all started somewhere, but start working in a chess engine at your level does feels odd, not sure if someone is going to take the time to rewrite that for you , but you will 100% encounter other problems along the way that you will not know how to solve, my advice would be to leave this on hold, focus on the basics and then come back and smash that code with your brand new knowledge